# How to format tooltip in echarts4r

Tags: r, visualization

Using the library `echarts4r`, I'd like to format the tooltip when using the calendar.

Adding the another line to [John Coene's example](http://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/chart_types.html)

```
library(echarts4r)
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day")
values <- rnorm(length(dates), 20, 6)

year <- data.frame(date = dates, values = values)

year %>% 
  e_charts(date) %>% 
  e_calendar(range = "2018") %>% 
  e_heatmap(values, coord.system = "calendar") %>% 
  e_visual_map(max = 30) %>% 
  e_title("Calendar", "Heatmap") %>%
  e_tooltip(trigger = "item", show = TRUE)
```

This shows tooltip of the value `1.23456` when mouseover a cell in the calendar .
How do I format the value so it shows `my value is 1.2`.

I've tried to understand using the [formatter](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#tooltip.formatter) in echarts documentation, however I'm not sure what to do with the `a, b, c, d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the vignette (https://github.com/JohnCoene/echarts4r/blob/master/vignettes/tooltip.Rmd), it looks as though it's necessary to format in java script. One possible version is

```
year %>%
  e_charts(date) %>%
  e_calendar(range = "2018") %>%
  e_heatmap(values, coord.system = "calendar") %>%
  e_visual_map(max = 30) %>%
  e_title("Calendar", "Heatmap") %>%
  e_tooltip(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
                                    function(params){
                                    return('value: ' +
parseFloat((params.value[1] * 10) / 10).toFixed(1))
                                    }
                                    ")
)
```

This approach shows the name 'value' - not necessary and can be removed if you want to show only the numeric value. This also rounds to the nearest tenth - not sure if that was wanted. To display more than one value include '< br >/' (without spaces around 'br') to create a line break in the tooltip display (an example is in the vignette).

Comment: This works and answers the question.  I'm also trying to add a newline to the name so it changes to 'value \n' however this doesn't seem to work - the heatmap doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it very simply as follows:

```
year$values_rounded <- round(year$values, digits = 1)
year %>% 
  e_charts(date) %>% 
  e_calendar(range = "2018") %>% 
  e_heatmap(values_rounded, coord.system = "calendar") %>% 
  e_visual_map(max = 30) %>% 
  e_title("Calendar", "Heatmap") %>%
  e_tooltip(trigger = "item", show = TRUE)
```

If rounding to the first digit wasn't what you were looking for, let me know.

Comment: This works if all I wanted to show was the value - it doesn't let me add text to the tip.

Answer (score 0):

pay attentiom to line:
e_heatmap(values, coord.system = "calendar") %>%

the right one is:
e_heatmap(values, coord_system = "calendar") %>%

Comment: This is suggestion for correction in code of question, this should be put as comment, rather than separate answer